# How to pass an interface pointer to a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, com, interface, marshalling

**Note:**

- Using **raw Win32** CreateTheard() API
- No MFC
- An interface is simply a pointer to a vtable

**Question:**

- How to pass an interface pointer to a thread?

**Illustration:**

```
IS8Simulation *pis8 = NULL;

...

CoCreateInstance(
                 clsid,
                 NULL,
                 CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
                 __uuidof(IS8Simulation),
                 (void **) &pis8);



...

hThread = CreateThread(
                NULL,
                0,
                SecondaryThread,
                //interface pointer pis8
                0,
                &dwGenericThreadID);

...

DWORD WINAPI SecondaryThread(LPVOID iValue)
{
    //using iValue accordingly
    //E.g.: iValue->Open
```

Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As was stated below, passing a `COM` interface pointer between threads in not safe.

Assuming you know what you are doing:

```
hThread = CreateThread(
                NULL,
                        0,
                        SecondaryThread,
                        (LPVOID) pis8
                        0,
                        &dwGenericThreadID);

DWORD WINAPI SecondaryThread(LPVOID iValue)
{
   ((IS8Simulation*) iValue)->Open();
}
```

Thread safe version:

```
void MainThread()
{
    IStream* psis8;
    HRESULT res = CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream (IID_IS8SIMULATION, pis8, &psis8);
    if (FAILED(res))
         return;
    hThread = CreateThread(
                NULL,
                0,
                SecondaryThread,
                (LPVOID) psis8
                0,
                &dwGenericThreadID
          );
}

DWORD WINAPI SecondaryThread(LPVOID iValue)
{
   IS8Simulation* pis8;
   HRESULT res = CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream((IStream*) iValue, IID_IS8SIMULATION, &pis8);
   if (FAILED(res))
      return (DWORD) res;
   pis8->Open();
}
```

Comment: This needs Interface Marshalling.

Answer (score 7):

If the interface in your question is a COM interface, the approach given by Quassnoi might not be sufficient.  You have to pay attention to the threading-model of the COM object in use.  If the secondary thread will join a separate COM apartment from the one that your COM object was created in, and if that object is not *apartment-agile*, you'll need to marshal that interface pointer so that the secondary thread gets a proxy, and not a direct pointer to the object.

A COM object is normally made apartment-agile by using a special implementation of IMarshal.  The simplest approach is to aggregate the Free Threaded Marshaler.

Some useful links...

- [CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693316.aspx)
- [GlobalInterfaceTable (GIT)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693729(VS.85).aspx)
- [CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694500.aspx)

Update: About the Free-threaded Marshaler...

It's clear from comments on this topic that some people would recommend that you never touch the FTM.  While "Effective COM" is an excellent book, I think some of its recommendations are open to interpretation.  Item 33 says "Beware the FTM"; it does not say "Never use the FTM".  Very wisely it advises caution particularly when your apartment-agile object holds references to other objects, because they might not be apartment-agile.  So really the advice is: think carefully when building apartment-agile objects, whether or not they use the FTM to achieve their agility.  If you're sure you can build an apartment-agile object, I see no reason why you wouldn't use the FTM to achieve that.

Comment: FTM has dangerous aspects (see Effective COM, item 33, "Beware the Free-Threaded Marshaler")

Comment: The GIT is very useful though.

Answer (score 2):

You basically need to do the following:

- `CoMashalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` ==> you get an IStream interface.
- pass that IStream to the thread, e.g. as Quassnoi said.
- in SecondaryThread, call `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream` to get the interface (or a proxy to it, if necessary).

Do not release the IStream interface unless creating the thread fails, and don't exit the thread until yu have called `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream`.

COM runtime will create the proxy for you automatically. The proxy ensures that e.g. an apartment-threaded COM component is called on the thread that created it. However, this also requires that:

- The interface is IDispatch, or proxy/stub components are registered for the interface
- the threadthat created the component has a message loop and processes messages

Comment: Where can I find more information about a "message loop" is that similar to Win32 API: WaitForSingleObject() ?